# How to add multiple parameters in DO-WHILE loop in C

Tags: c, do-while, cs50, logical-or, logical-and

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("height: ");
    }
    while(n<1&&n>8);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

im writing a program to print a square with hashes,but my while in the Do loop wont work.
i want it to accept values only between 1 and 8 inclusive,but it wont work and wouldnt prompt again if i enter values out of the parameter.but it works if I only put a single parameter in the while loop e.g. `n<1`.
please help me,im a beginner.

Comment: `while(n<1&&n>8)` --> do you see the non sense of this expression?

Comment: Make a habit of speaking stuff like `while(n<1&&n>8);` out loud. "While n is less than 1 and greater than 8". Apply common sense from there to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very easy and it is not related to the programming only simple math and logic

`while(n<1&&n>8)`

**If `n` is lower than `1` it cannot be larger than `8` at the same time**.

Answer (score 2):

**Reason for not working** : `while( n<1 && n>8);` See the image for clarity. There is no value in the intersection. I mean there is no number, less than one and greater than 8.

[image]

**Solution** : Use `while(n < 1 || n > 8);` for `n` values between 1 and 8 inclusive.

Comment: This will loop forever until the user enters a value outside the required range.

Comment: @r3mainer  `i want it to accept values only between 1 and 8 inclusive,`. This was OP statement.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula That is correct. So when the user enters a value from 1 to 8 inclusive, the loop should ***end***, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a number that would be simultaneously less than 1 and greater than 8.:)

```
n<1&&n>8
```

A simple way to write correctly the condition of the loop is to write at first the condition that a number shall satisfy. That is

```
1 <= n && n <= 8
```

and then to apply negation to the condition

```
do { /*...*/ } while ( !( 1 <= n && n <= 8 ) );
```

Then using rules for logical operations you can write for example

```
do { /*...*/ } while ( !( 1 <= n ) || !( n <= 8 ) );
```

and at last

```
do { /*...*/ } while ( ( 1 > n ) || ( n > 8 ) );
```

or

```
do { /*...*/ } while ( n < 1 || n > 8 );
```